# T5 model custom vocabulary

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

Is there a way to choose my custom vocabulary in T5-model while fine-tuning for a text summarization task?

I tried using a sentencepiece model to create my custom tokenizer but the model predicted some tokens which was not present in my tokenizer and hence the tokenizer takes it as an unknown token.

Comment: Please give us a [minimal reporducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3):

It is okay to add few tokens but you can not be using a totally different vocabulary and fine-tuning at the same time! The pre-trained weights are trained with the pre-trained vocabulary :) If you change the vocabulary, the trained weights become meaningless and invalid! If you want to use another vocabulary you have to train from scratch! To add tokens to vocabulary you can for example do:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer.add_tokens(['new', 'codekali', 'blabla'])
model = Bert.from_pretrained(model_name, return_dict=False)
     
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
```

The last line is important because you need to tell the model that the number of tokens is changed.

Comment: Thanks @Berkay. This was late but useful

Answer (score 0):

You can add new tokens using the `Tokenizer.add_tokens()`. More details can be found at huggingface [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/tokenization_utils.html#PreTrainedTokenizer.add_tokens).

Comment: Add a small number of tokens if fine. But I need to use only my vocabulary. I don't want to use the vocabulary on which t5 model was built... But doing that the model generates unk tokens as it maps to the tokens if the vocabulary on which it was trained

Comment: You will have to mention specifically your custom vocab so that it doesn't use the default one.

Comment: Where does that option exist to specify my custom vocab?

Comment: I am not sure about it but one workaround would be to rename your custom vocab file as the original vocab file.